# how to extract value of a dictionary that is inside a list

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

how will you extract the value of a authorNanme from a given distionary?

```
{'Auther_name': [{'authorCleanUrl': 'jeffrey-brown',
                  'authorName': 'Jeffrey Brown',
                  'authorSalesRank': 13828,
                  'idAuthor': 232349}]
```

i tried severel ways but failed  ..

Comment: ```a.get('Auther_name')[0].get('authorName')```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'Auther_name': [{'authorCleanUrl': 'jeffrey-brown',
              'authorName': 'Jeffrey Brown',
              'authorSalesRank': 13828,
              'idAuthor': 232349}]}
print(data['Auther_name'][0]['authorName'])
```

Try this one